# How to publish an auditable EOS Smart Contract in a trustless way?

Tags: smart-contract

In Ethereum every smart contract is public. This can obviously have downsides, but an important upside is the auditability and trustworthiness of contracts. In EOS by default contracts are NOT public. How can I review if - f.e. BetDice - uses a trustable and fair Smart Contract?

How can a (d)app builders prove their integrity? How can they publish their smart contract and prove that this specific code is running?

Brandon Blumar referred to a solution in this (amazing) talk around min 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiimIJnVXxU

Comment: publish your code on e.g. eospark or on any public platform along with the compiling instructions for people to compare the wasm

Comment: The code of the contract is publicly available, you can use `cleos get code` (https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-code) to get wasm. There needs to be better tools to show the contract code in a readable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the developer makes the code public, then you can compile it using `eosio.cdt`, and then compare the SHA256 hash to the one stored on chain. The one on chain can be accessed using: `cleos get code account_name`. If the 2 hashes match, then the open-source code is indeed the code that is stored on the smart contract account.